# Youtube Iframe API multiple video's start each video with a custom button

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-instances, youtube-iframe-api

I have a script that loads multiple videos. Each video has an overlay and a custom button.

I'm currently struggling with the following.

Each video has an `.icon--play` and A `.video-overlay` element. When I click on one of the `.icon-play` buttons I want the video to start.

I also want the `.video-overlay` to disappear. I have this working when it's just one video.

But I can't figure out how to get this working with multiple video's. The video's are not static and are loaded dynamically.

There is an `array` with all the `players`. That should help me control them individually. But I'm not that good at js to understand how I must do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

At the moment, with the below code all video's start simultaneously.

```js
import YouTubePlayer from 'youtube-player';

export default class ytPlayer {
    constructor() {
        const videoOverlay = document.querySelector('.player-overlay');
        const videoButton = document.querySelector('.icon--play');
        /**
         * @see https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events
         */
        const stateNames = {
            '-1': 'unstarted',
            0: 'ended',
            1: 'playing',
            2: 'paused',
            3: 'buffering',
            5: 'video cued',
        };

        if (videoButton) {
            const tag = document.createElement('script');

            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            const players = {};
            window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
                console.log('YouTube Iframe API Ready');

                $('.video').each(function () {
                    const videoButton = document.querySelector('.icon--play');
                    // videoButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    //     videoOverlay.classList.add('fade');
                    // });
                    players[$(this).attr('id')] = new YT.Player($(this).attr('id'), {
                        videoId: $(this).attr('data-video'),
                        rel: 1,
                        host: 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com',
                        events: {
                            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange($(this).attr('id'))
                        }
                    });

                });

            };

            function onPlayerStateChange(player_id) {

                $(".icon--play").click(function () {
                    $(".video-overlay").hide();
                    $(players[player_id])[0].playVideo();
                });

                return function (event) {

                    if (players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 3 || players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 1) {

                        //stop the auto scrolling
                        console.log("You clicked " + player_id);
                        players[player_id].playVideo();
                    }

                    if (players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 0 || players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 2) {
                        //start auto scrolling.
                        console.log("the video is paused " + player_id);
                        videoOverlay.classList.remove('fade');

                    }

                    if (players[player_id].getPlayerState() == -1 || players[player_id].getPlayerState() == 2) {
                        //start auto scrolling.
                        console.log("the video is playing or paused " + player_id);
                        $(videoButton ).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                            players[player_id].stopVideo();
                        })
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare the button/events related to `this` video (Read about functions like https://api.jquery.com/children/) **read about `traverse dom`. In your code, you use the same `class` for all videos button (The scope should be the video, not the document). `button-1` should play `video-1` and so on. The same idea  her for example: `onPlayerStateChange` `$(".video-overlay").hide();` This code hide all overlays (But you should `scope` to the correct `overlay` related to `this` object by `traverse dom`).

Comment: thank you that makes sense thanks! I'll start reading right away. Als go ahead and mark your answer as the sollution because it's the right way to go about it.